# jquery ui selectable get id?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, get, selectable

How do I get the 'id' of an item in a selectable list, if the list is created dynamically?

```
  <ul id="selectable">
  <li id='1'>..</li>
      .
      .
      <li...
  </ul>
```

I tried `var num = $('#selecable :selected').attr( "option" , 'id' );` but get only [object Object]...

What is the right way?

Comment: IDs can't be numbers, or rather can't start with them, make sure your IDs have a prefix of some sort so they're valid.

Comment: @Nick Craver  Good point, I missed that when I looked at that.

Comment: your "#selecable " has a typo

Comment: `$('.ui-selected', this ).attr('id');`

Comment: You can use this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621111/jquery-selectable-get-text-value/35511166#35511166
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

For completeness, if an element is selected, the plugin adds a class `ui-selected` to the element. So you can get the ID of current selected element via:

```
$('#selectable .ui-selected').attr('id');
```

But be aware that **multiple** elements can be selected.

---

The jQuery UI selectable plugin [calls a callback whenever you select an element](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selected), you just have to provide it:

```
$("#selectable" ).selectable({
   selected: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

That said, as Nick already mentions, IDs cannot start with a digit.

[`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) only works on `option` elements.

Answer (score 5):

This version does not require specific class names. Use `$(ui.selected).attr('id')` to get the (last) selected element's ID:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        alert( $(ui.selected).attr('id') );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The list of selected id's would be: edit: better methinnks

```
$('#selectable').selectable(function(){
    selected:function(){ 
        var idlist = $(this).attr('id');
        //do something with the list...of id's
    }
});
```

Comment: yea, I had a brain cramp, edited the silly thing :) while you were commenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#selectable').selectable(function(){
    selected: function(event, ui)
    {
     jQuery(".ui-selected", this).each(function() 
     {
          var objID=jQuery(this).attr("id");
     });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#selectable').selectable( function() {
    selected: function(event, ui)
    {
        alert(ui.selected.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please give some explanation along with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

check this..

```
  $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
   var index = $( "#selectable li" ).attr(id);

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function () {
            var id = $(".ui-selected", this).attr("id");
            //alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You might want to explain your answer some. SO is not just about answering questions, but about teaching people how things work.